# Django form post saving multiple records that violate the unique integrity check

Tags: django-forms

I've got a model for purposes of storing the scoring of a football game by quarter:

```
class BoxScoreByQuarter( models.Model ):
    game_participant = models.ForeignKey( GameParticipant, verbose_name='game participant' )
    first_quarter = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField( blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='first quarter' )
    second_quarter = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField( blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='second quarter' )
    third_quarter = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField( blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='third quarter' )
    fourth_quarter = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField( blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='fourth quarter' )
    overtime = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField( blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='overtime' )
    final_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField( blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='final score' )
```

game_participant is a FK to the GameParticipant model and there should never be more than one BoxScoreByQuarter per participant in a game.

My view checks for the existence of a BoxScoreByQuarter and either updates it or creates a new one.

```
        try:
            initial_box = BoxScoreByQuarter.objects.get( game_participant=participant )
            box_score = BoxScoreByQuarterForm( submitted_data, instance=initial_box )
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            box_score = BoxScoreByQuarterForm( submitted_data )
            initial_box = None

        if box_score.is_valid():
            game_results = box_score.save()
```

For some reason, the save occasionally results in two or even more BoxScoreByQuarter records for a given participant. It doesn't happen all the time and there doesn't appear to be any pattern to it.

Is there a more reliable way of handling the form save that would guarantee the integrity of the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want one `BoxScoreByQuarter` per `GameParticipant` then you should be using a `OneToOneField` instead.

Comment: That makes sense. Changing it results in this error: Caught an exception while rendering: 'GameParticipant' object has no attribute 'boxscorebyquarter_set'

Comment: That's because the `_set` manager does not exist for `OneToOneField`s.

Comment: I get the same error within the Django admin when attempting to open GameParticipant. My GameParticipant model includes game = models.ForeignKey( Game ) and my Game model includes participants = models.ManyToManyField( 'organization.Team', through='GameParticipant', related_name='game' )

Comment: I've found the issue with the admin. I've got some functions in my model which make use of the _set manager. Once I unwind those in my model and any templates I should be ok.